# The OCSP response is not yet valid (contains a date in the future)

Tags: ssl, firefox

I'm getting this error when opening the site:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to http://practiceti.me 

The OCSP response is not yet valid (contains a date in the future). 
(Error code: sec_error_ocsp_future_response)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fix your local clock.

An OCSP response is valid between particular times contained within it.  In general, if something comes from the future, x.509 implementations will deem it invalid (since obviously the timestamp or system time must be incorrect).

However, since you're connecting via http, and not https, I don't see why you might be having trouble... certificates shouldn't be involved.

Comment: Alo make sure the correct Timezone is selected. In my case it was Timezone. Thanks.